# Disable Live Website Feeds

Tags: google-chrome

Does Google Chrome have an option to disable dynamic website content?

In other words, once the page has loaded, do not load new notifications, live feed stories, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use: [Quick Javascript Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-javascript-switcher/geddoclleiomckbhadiaipdggiiccfje?hl=en)

> Quick Javascript Switcher is a Chrome extension that enable / disable JavaScript on the fly by hostname, and subdomain.
>   (unlike to Chris Pederick's "Web Developer" extension who globally disables javascript)
>
> For example, disable javascript on www.google.fr not disable js on translate.google.fr
>
> To disable javascript permanently, open the right click contextual menu, and there is a shortcut to open the Chrome